# JPA With hibernate, setting AvailableSettings.USE_CLASS_ENHANCER property to true throws java.lang.ClassCircularityError

Tags: spring-mvc, maven-3, tomcat8, hibernate-entitymanager, load-time-weaving

I setup spring application. Everything works fine. But when I set Hibernate AvailableSettings.USE_CLASS_ENHANCER property to true then I get `java.lang.ClassCircularityError`.

Here is my configuration. First of all I am using log4j2. Here are my log4j2 files.

log4j-xinclude-appenders.xml:

```
<appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>

    <RollingFile name="WroxFileAppender" fileName="${filename}.log" filePattern="${filename}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log">      
        <PatternLayout pattern= "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %X{id} %X{username} %-5level %c{36} %l: %msg%n" />

        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </Policies>

        <DefaultRolloverStrategy min="1" max="4" />
    </RollingFile>      
</appenders>
```

log4j-xinclude-loggers.xml:

```
<loggers>
    <root level="warn">
        <!--  
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="WroxFileAppender" />
        -->
    </root>

    <logger name="my.package" level="info" />
    <logger name="org.apache" level="info" />
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="info" /> 
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="info" />
</loggers>
```

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" status="WARN">

    <Properties>
        <Property name="filename">D:/Basit/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/logs/support</Property>
    </Properties>

    <xi:include href="log4j-xinclude-appenders.xml" />
    <xi:include href="log4j-xinclude-loggers.xml" />
</configuration>
```

Here is my Spring setup

```
@Order(1)
public class FrameworkBootstrap implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();
    ....

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(RootContextConfiguration.class);
    container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    webContext.register(WebServletContextConfiguration.class);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("springWebDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(webContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement(null, 20_971_520L, 41_943_040L, 512_000));
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    ....
```

RootContextConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
@ComponentScan(.. )
@Import({AsyncConfig.class, PersistenceConfig.class,  EmailConfig.class, SecurityConfiguration.class })
public class RootContextConfiguration {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ....
    }

    ....
}
```

PersistenceConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.PROXY, proxyTargetClass = false, order = 2)
@EnableJpaRepositories(...)
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Inject 
    private LoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
         JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
         return lookup.getDataSource("jdbc/dev");
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {  

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect");
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
        factory.setDataSource(this.dataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
        factory.setSharedCacheMode(SharedCacheMode.ENABLE_SELECTIVE);
        factory.setValidationMode(ValidationMode.NONE);
        factory.setLoadTimeWeaver(this.loadTimeWeaver); // TODO: remove when SPR-10856 fixed
        factory.setJpaPropertyMap(this.jpaHibernateProperties());
        return factory;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> jpaHibernateProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new Hashtable<>();
         properties.put(AvailableSettings.SCHEMA_GEN_DATABASE_ACTION, "none");
         properties.put(AvailableSettings.USE_CLASS_ENHANCER, "true");
         ....
         return properties; 
    }
}
```

Now if I un-comment my loggers in `log4j-xinclude-loggers.xml` like

```
<root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    <appender-ref ref="WroxFileAppender" />  
</root>
```

Then I get this exception trace

```
17:12:00.572 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.0.Final}
Sep 15, 2015 5:12:00 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase addTransformer
INFO: Added class file transformer [Standard ClassFileTransformer wrapping JPA transformer:     org.hibernate.jpa.internal.enhance.EnhancingClassTransformerImpl@2cf5594c] to web application [LMS-Java8].
2015-09-15 17:12:00,986 ERROR Recursive call to appender WroxFileAppender
Sep 15, 2015 5:12:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassCircularityError: org/apache/logging/log4j/core/impl/ThrowableProxy
at         org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent.getThrownProxy(Log4jLogEvent.java:323)
at     org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.ExtendedThrowablePatternConverter.format(ExtendedThrowablePatternConverter.java:64)
at     org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternFormatter.format(PatternFormatter.java:36)
at     org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.toSerializable(PatternLayout.java:196)
at     org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.toSerializable(PatternLayout.java:55)
at     org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractStringLayout.toByteArray(AbstractStringLayout.java:71)
at     org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:108)
at     org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.append(RollingFileAppender.java:88)
at     org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:99)
at     org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:430)
at     org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:409)
at     org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:412)
at     org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:367)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:112)
at     org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:722)
at     org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:693)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.Log4jLog.error(Log4jLog.java:116)
at     org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:358)
at     org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at     org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17:12:01.046 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO      org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Sep 15 17:11:57 PKT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 15, 2015 5:12:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Sep 15, 2015 5:12:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/LMS-Java8] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 15, 2015 5:12:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Sep 15, 2015 5:12:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassCircularityError: org/apache/logging/log4j/core/impl/ThrowableProxy
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent.getThrownProxy(Log4jLogEvent.java:323)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.ExtendedThrowablePatternConverter.format(ExtendedThrowablePatternConverter.java:64)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternFormatter.format(PatternFormatter.java:36)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.toSerializable(PatternLayout.java:196)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.toSerializable(PatternLayout.java:55)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractStringLayout.toByteArray(AbstractStringLayout.java:71)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:108)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.append(RollingFileAppender.java:88)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:99)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:430)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:409)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:412)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:367)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:112)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:722)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:693)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.Log4jLog.error(Log4jLog.java:116)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.ClassFileTransformerAdapter.transform(ClassFileTransformerAdapter.java:66)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2648)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2428)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:859)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1301)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:954)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:583)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4774)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5390)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Why there is line `2015-09-15 17:12:00,986 ERROR Recursive call to appender WroxFileAppender` ? See its pattern is different then I defined in my appenders.

Now if I comment out my `WroxFileAppender` Then I get the same error for my `Console appender.`. If I comment out my both apenders. Then I get the following exception trace

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Sep 15, 2015 5:20:08 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase addTransformer
INFO: Added class file transformer [Standard ClassFileTransformer wrapping JPA transformer: org.hibernate.jpa.internal.enhance.EnhancingClassTransformerImpl@781e38b3] to web application [LMS-Java8].
Sep 15, 2015 5:20:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not weave class [org/springframework/util/ConcurrentReferenceHashMap$EntrySet]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.ClassFileTransformerAdapter.transform(ClassFileTransformerAdapter.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2648)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2428)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:859)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1301)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
at org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.entrySet(ConcurrentReferenceHashMap.java:366)
at java.util.AbstractMap$1$1.<init>(AbstractMap.java:332)
at java.util.AbstractMap$1.iterator(AbstractMap.java:331)
at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.clearClassLoader(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:164)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.resetCommonCaches(AbstractApplicationContext.java:874)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:559)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCircularityError: org/hibernate/bytecode/enhance/spi/Enhancer
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.enhance.EnhancingClassTransformerImpl.transform(EnhancingClassTransformerImpl.java:38)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.ClassFileTransformerAdapter.transform(ClassFileTransformerAdapter.java:56)
... 23 more

INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Sep 15, 2015 5:36:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not weave class [org/springframework/web/context/ContextCleanupListener]
at     org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.ClassFileTransformerAdapter.transform(ClassFileTransformerAdapter.java:68)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2648)
....
```

Why I am getting these ClassCircularityError errors. What I am doing wrong ? I am using `Maven, Java 8 update 60, Spring 4.2.1, Hibernate 5.0.2, Spring-data-JPA 1.9.0`. Are maven dependencies causing these issues ?

If I set property to `false` like `properties.put(AvailableSettings.USE_CLASS_ENHANCER, "false");` Then everything works perfectly fine. I want to use this because of Lazy loading issues cause by `(mappedBy)` on inverse side of JPA.

Thanks

### **Edit**

my POM

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <javax.annotation-api.version>1.2</javax.annotation-api.version>
    <javax.persistence.version>2.1.0</javax.persistence.version>
    <javax.transaction-api.version>1.2</javax.transaction-api.version>
    <spring.framework.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    <spring-ws-core.version>2.2.2.RELEASE</spring-ws-core.version>
    <xmlschema-core.version>2.2.1</xmlschema-core.version>
    <spring.security.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <spring-data-jpa.version>1.9.0.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
    <wsdl4j.version>1.6.3</wsdl4j.version>
    <commons-lang3.version>3.4</commons-lang3.version>
    <org.apache.velocity-version>1.7</org.apache.velocity-version>
    <validation-api.version>1.1.0.Final</validation-api.version>
    <hibernate-validator.version>5.2.2.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
    <hibernate-entitymanager.version>5.0.2.Final</hibernate-entitymanager.version>
    <sqljdbc4.version>4.0</sqljdbc4.version>
    <javassist.version>3.20.0-GA</javassist.version>
    <jboss-logging.version>3.3.0.Final</jboss-logging.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <jackson.version>2.6.2</jackson.version> 
    <log4j.version>2.4</log4j.version>
    <slf4j-api.verion>1.7.12</slf4j-api.verion>
    <javax.mail.version>1.5.4</javax.mail.version>

    <tomcat-directory-path>D:\Basit\apache-tomcat-8.0.27</tomcat-directory-path>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.annotation-api.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>${validation-api.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>${jboss-logging.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-ws-core.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
                <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>${wsdl4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
        <version>${xmlschema-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.persistence.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.transaction-api.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-entitymanager.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>${javassist.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-api.verion}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>${sqljdbc4.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.mail.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
        ...
                </executions>
            </plugin>       
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                ...
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                <outputDirectory>${tomcat-directory-path}\webapps</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```